# How to select row by row and set to array in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to select row by row and set to array in MYSQL

I have this code:

```
  public function getWinnerBonus($email){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM winers WHERE `email` = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    // return user details
    if ($result){
        $respons               = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["WinnerInfo"]["price"] = $respons["price"];
        $response["WinnerInfo"]["level"] = $respons["level"];
        $response["WinnerInfo"]["win_date"] = $respons["win_date"];
        $response["WinnerInfo"]["payed"] = $respons["payed"];
        $response["WinnerInfo"]["pay_date"] = $respons["pay_date"];

    }else{
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

but this code return just first founded row

How to select row by row and set to array in MYSQL?

Comment: Sidenote: `GROUP BY` comes after a `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html - Your `mysql_error()` should have thrown you a syntax error, but you didn't share that with us.

Comment: *"but this code return just first founded row"* - I sincerely doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the result set not just one time.

```
$respons = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $respons[$i]["error"] = FALSE;
  $respons[$i]["WinnerInfo"]["price"] = $row["price"];
  $respons[$i]["WinnerInfo"]["level"] = $row["level"];
  $respons[$i]["WinnerInfo"]["win_date"] = $row["win_date"];
  $respons[$i]["WinnerInfo"]["payed"] = $row["payed"];
  $respons[$i]["WinnerInfo"]["pay_date"] = $row["pay_date"];
  ++$i;
}
```

Note: Never use **mysql_** functions, they are deprecated. Use **mysqli_** or PDO instead, along with a prepared statement.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Also make sure that you have successfully connected to your database using the same API as your query.

Different MySQL APIs do not intermix.

Consult the following:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
- [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` I think that should read as `while ($respons= mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: `GROUP BY` comes after a `WHERE` clause. That I know for sure. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Tank you @Fred-ii- , but I got error: `Notice: Undefined index: win_date in`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you have to loop over the result set. Here is how you could do it:

```
$resultArray = array();
while($response = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM) {
    $resultArray[] = $response; //This adds one result set to the array
}
```

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Undefined variable 'response'